# Valuemember ComboBox

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, vb.net, vb

Tengo un ComboBox con modelos de camisetas que relleno automáticamente cogiendo datos de una tabla SQL.
Lo relleno de la siguiente manera:

```
   DT = New DataTable
   DA.Fill(DT)
   ComboBox_intrcam.ValueMember = "ID"
   ComboBox_intrcam.DisplayMember = "Nombre"
   ComboBox_intrcam.DataSource = DT
```

Ahora el problema es, hay veces que el modelo de camiseta es el mismo pero lo que cambia es el color.
Lo que me gustaría es que desplegable me apareciese: Modelo(Color)

Ahora mismo me aparece: Modelo

El color lo cogería también de un campo de la base de datos.

Había probado en el Displaymember concatenando el otro campo pero no funciona.

Algo parecido a lo que me gustaría seria:

```
Modelo1(Azul)
Modelo1(Verde)
Modelo2(Azul)
```

Mi consulta SQL es esta:

```
query = "select * from GEN0 where enVenta = 1"
```

Comment: Concaténalo en la consulta SQL

Comment: Mi consulta SQL es esta:
`query = "select * from GEN0 where enVenta = 1"
 conexion_odbc_cam_llenar_combo() `
Y luego haria lo que he puesto en el post.
Es posible concatenando como dices?

Comment: Claro, algo así: `select *, (modelo + ' (' + color + ')' ) as displayModColor from GEN0 where enVenta = 1` Siendo modelo y color los nombres de tu columnas y luego en DisplayMember colocas `ComboBox_intrcam.DisplayMember = "displayModColor "`

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha funcionado!!

Comment: BrianON, agrega esa información a tu pregunta. @Yussef, agrega eso a la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes generar concatener el campo directamente en la consulta, de esta manera:

```
select *, (modelo + ' (' + color + ')' ) as displayModColor from GEN0 where enVenta = 1
```

Siendo `modelo` y `color` los nombres de tus columnas, y luego en DisplayMember colocas

```
ComboBox_intrcam.DisplayMember = "displayModColor";
```